# Magento if product option selected then open text field

Tags: customer, input

i want to create a product (shirt) which can be tailored.  The customer would click the option to tailor, adding cost of tailoring to price and a text field would open letting the customer enter their length, width, etc.  I am able to do the first part when I customize the product, but I need it to be linked to the text input from the customer letting me know their tailoring measurements.

I have tried looking everywhere but what I am finding are ways to customize a configurable product using drop down menu.  Anyone know how this can be done?  Besides shirts this could be useful in multiple situations.

Answer (score 0):

Just use custom options? With custom options you can add text fields and they are saved through the process.. quote -> order -> creditmemo...